# How to structure my database model for a simple web application and organize my SQL data model

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am working on a web app. I have a question about the SQL parts. I am currently creating a food rating interface. The user should be able to login and then rate the food.

Currently I use a custom database (users) for the login page. I also use a separate database (review) for the reviews. my current database structure makes no sense.

In the attached image you can see the tables, they are currently separate databases with only this one table each. I use MySQL extension in VSCode.

How can I combine the tables into one database? I am looking for some ideas for this problem.

Preferably the username should only be needed for login and not have to be entered separately in the rating (as unfortunately still current).

In the future, the user should be directed after login, to a page where he can select his dish, then he should rate it. Each dish should save the ratings individually, to distinguish this of course.

[image]

Comment: If that's a web app you likely yet need some kind of session management – session id e. g. set via cookie and another table `session` with `id`, foreign key `userid` and a timestamp holding last communication time – so with every new request receiving via session id you'd update the timestamp – unless too much time elapsed, for when you'd invalidate the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you do use the `user` table as a reference for reviews, and also a table `dish` with the details of each dish.
Here are suggested table definitions, to fine-tune to your needs:

Credits to Mishi for the improvement to `foreign key` syntax to make it more portable.

I've put the creation of the table `review` last because some SQL engines check that the table exists when we declare a foreign key.

> ```
> create table users
> (
> uid int primary key,
> username varchar(25),
> password varchar(25),
> created_at date
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table dish
> (
> did int primary key,
> nom varchar(25),
> description varchar(250),
> last_rating int
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table review
> (
> rid int primary key,
> user_id int ,
> dish_id int ,
> user_rating int ,
> user_reveiw varchar(100),
> review_date datetime,
> foreign key (user_id) references users(uid),
> foreign key (dish_id) references dish(did)
> );
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=77093eeccd337fd983c602fca888231d)*

Comment: thanks for your answer @Kendle i will try it :)

Can u tell me whats wrong with this expression:

CREATE TABLE bewertung (
  id int NOT NULL,
  userid int NOT NULL,
  rating int NOT NULL,
  review VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
  created DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (userid) REFERENCES users.id
);

i get:   Can't create table `databasename`.`bewertung` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Is the table users in the same database? if not you have to use the format "REFERENCES datebase.table.column" and not simply "REFERENCES table.column" as in my suggestion and your code.

Comment: yeah it is in the same database

Comment: While trying your solution i get the following error (creating review table)

EXECUTE FAIL:

  create table review ( review_id int primary key, user_id int , dish_id int , user_rating int , user_reveiw varchar(100), review_date datetime foreign key (user_id) references users.uid, foreign key (dish_id) references dish.did )

Message :

  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'foreign key (user_id) references users.uid, foreign key (dish_id) references ...' at line 9

What is wrong

Comment: your table defenition is working in dbfiddle - check that table users contains a column id which is unique

Comment: @michi there was a comma missing at the end of a column defenition. I've added it. Sorry

Comment: thanks but there is another error now :(

EXECUTE FAIL:

  create table review ( review_id int primary key, user_id int , dish_id int , user_rating int , user_reveiw varchar(100), review_date datetime, foreign key (user_id) references users.uid, foreign key (dish_id) references dish.did )

Message :

  Can't create table `databasename`.`review` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wqwDFKeKZeRLrTBdPhdTiU/1 not working here as well ::( @Kendle

Comment: the correct answer is

 "foreign key (user_id) references users(uid),
foreign key (dish_id) references dish(did)"

it is not working with . use () instead!

Comment: Thank you @michi it was working on DBfiddle with . But I must have been on a different database than mySQL

Comment: please update your answer :)

Comment: For consistency: `review_id` -> `rid` – though I personally would have preferred simply `id` for *any* id...

Comment: Thank you @Aconcagua - I've changed to rid. I like to have unique column names in the schema to avoid the need to use the table names in the field list of every query. I've also put the creation of review to last. Some database engines block on the foreign key if the referred table hasn't been created.

Comment: @Kendle u missed again the comma after datetime